# Nutch ReCrawl and extract new links

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

I am working on a News gathering application. It should daily monitor more than 300 sites and send new URLs(new news links) to Solr(which is our indexer module). I have installed NUTCH and applied all required configuration. everything work fine ,but its re-crawling module dose not work. I red many articles (such as http://pascaldimassimo.com/2010/06/11/how-to-re-crawl-with-nutch/ and http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IntranetRecrawl) and applied their configurations but unfortunately non of them works for me. Is there any scrips or configuration for my issue ?

I also use NUTCH 1.8.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not work"?
What is the system doing/not doing and what would you like it to be doing

Comment: "Full Crawl" works well. I mean I can crawl all seed URLs and store them in CrawlDB(And also Solr) but I would like to have some sort of "Incremental Crawl". I mean, I just want to FETCH update urls(new News)in each of 300 site.

Answer (score 0):

try making some changes to your nutch-site.xml

```
 <property> 
   <name>db.fetch.schedule.class</name> 
   <value>org.apache.nutch.crawl.AdaptiveFetchSchedule</value> 
  </property>

<property>
  <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description>The default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page (30 days).
  </description>
</property>
  <property>
  <name>db.fetch.interval.max</name>
          <!-- for now always re-fetch everything -->
  <value>10</value>
  <description>The maximum number of seconds between re-fetches of a page
  (less than one day). After this period every page in the db will be re-tried, no
   matter what is its status.
  </description>
</property>
```